Lipschitz function on the n-dimensional sphere
I am working through the proof of the concentration of measure phenomenon as in Albiac's Topics in Banach space theory (theorem 13.2.2 in the 2nd edition). We are working with a Lipschitz function $f: S^n \to \mathbf{R}$ with Lipschitz constant 1 and average $\int_{S^n} f d\sigma_n = 0$. The book then claims that $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in S^n$. This feels so logical, and yet I cannot prove it. Because the function is not defined on $R^n$, but only on $S^n$, I can't work it out. How could one prove this?

Is the metric on the sphere here the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ or great arc distance or something else?

It is induced by the normal Euclidean metric on $R^{n+1}$
